# ExtJS4 MessageBox Throws Error

Tags: extjs4, runtime-error

Using the following function:

```
function showError(ptitle,perror){
    Ext.Msg.show({
        title: ptitle,
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
        msg: perror,
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
    });
}
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ERROR' of undefined
```

I cannot see wheat is wrong with this code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the same code works at my place,
just try Ext.Msg.ERROR instead of Ext.MessageBox.ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
    title: ptitle,
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
    msg: perror,
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
});
```